# MySQL query by string and limit

Tags: mysql

I have a table "articles" that has a column "company" which has list of companies or an article type - crappy I know, but it's not my DB. :) Let's say there are *n* articles for each type. I need to select the first article (based on year, or any other criteria) that is of the type. Something like this:

```
select * from details where (company = 'aaa' or company = 'bbb' or ...)
```

I know what the types are, so they can be hardcoded. I need to limit only the first article for each type. Thanks!

EDIT

given the sample data:

```
id  company  copy   issue
------------------------
1   apple    'abc'  NULL
2   bmw      'abc'  NULL
3   ibm      'abc'  NULL
4   news     'abc'  2
5   news     'abc'  3
6   seagate  'abc'  NULL
7   events   'abc'  1
8   features 'abc'  5
9   samsung  'abc'  NULL
```

I need rows 4, 7, 8.

EDIT2

Sorry if I wasn't clear. Essentially the table contains two different types of data. One is company info, and one is article info. Basically I need to do this:

```
select * from articles where company = "news" order by issue limit 1;
select * from articles where company = "events" order by issue limit 1;
select * from articles where company = "features" order by issue limit 1;
```

but with a single query.

Comment: It really depends on the criteria.  It is hard with MySQL to select only fields from the first matching row in a group in a single query.

Comment: Where is your sortable data? What places row #4 before #5? Also, I can't see what distinguishes #7 and #8. Why not #1, #2, #3, etc?

Comment: That is the way the data was entered, the id is an auto increment. It's a bit more complex than that, but for ease let's assume that it's just the id that's different.

Comment: The company column illustrates that there are either companies (apple, ibm) or a type (news, features)

Comment: @Alex The obvious question is: how do you recognize which are types and which are companies?

Comment: They are hardcoded, meaning I know it will always be "news", "events", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps

```
select * from details d
where company in ('news', 'events', 'features')
and not exists (
    select 1 from details d_
    where d_.company = d.company
    and d_.id < d.id -- provide your sortable criteria here
)
```

Example here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb8f2/6

Comment: This would work, except that the company is a mixed type col: it can indicate a company or a type of article.

Comment: @Alex I've added Mosty's answer to the SQLFiddle so you can compare the two.

Comment: With some playing around this seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This query:

```
select t1.* from t t1
left join t t2
on t1.company = t2.company and t1.id > t2.id
where t2.id is null and t1.company in ('news', 'events', 'features')
```

will return:

```
+----+----------+------+
| ID | COMPANY  | COPY |
+----+----------+------+
|  4 | news     | abc  |
|  7 | events   | abc  |
|  8 | features | abc  |
+----+----------+------+
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Note: When you say `the first article` I assume the order is provided by the `ID` field

You can play with it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ba3a/1)

**Edit:**

After your edit, the query is almost the same, just change the ordering field to `issue` instead of `id`:

```
select t1.* from t t1
left join t t2
on t1.company = t2.company and t1.issue > t2.issue
where t2.id is null and t1.company in ('news', 'events', 'features')
```

Comment: Sorry to complicate things: it could be id, or it could be a date, or a magazine issue haven't gotten direction yet... What is "t", "t1", "t2" in your query?

Comment: `t` is the table name. `t1` and `t2` are table aliases. I don't get what you say about different orderings. The solution I provided results in your expected result. Can you update your example data to display your actual data and see why this doesn't work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "company" and "publication_date" are columns in table "details", then something like:

```
select * 
from details 
where company in ('aaa', 'bbb', ...)
and publication_date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-03-01' 
order by publication_date desc
limit 1
```

Comment: The IN clause is exactly what I need, but I also need to limit each type to just the first one. So if the query returns 4 'aaa' and 7 'bbb' I need just the first ones for each.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a `group by`.
Next you want to `order by` the *issue* column.
Then you only need the first row.

I used group concat to create a list,
then extract the first string in the ordered list `group_concat(copy order by copy)`.

```
select 
  id,
  company,
  substring(
    group_concat(copy order by copy),
    1,
    case when substring_index(group_concat(copy order by copy),',',1) > 1 
           then substring_index(group_concat(copy order by copy),',',1)-1
         else 1 end
    ) as copy
from details d
where company in ('news', 'events', 'features')
group by company
```

*the list `group_concat(copy order by copy)` cannot be too long though, which depends on your data.